# KendoUI - Remote Databinding Fails within "kendoWindow"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I made this topic once, but the information I had was a bit hard to follow and I did not get much help, so I am trying again after spending the day making a JSBIN sample.

I have a situation where I am using KendoUI to make a view model, and also to make some items within it, and when you click on sub-items that are drawn, it opens up a `KendoWindow` to let you edit them more specifically.

However, there is a problem with the `dataSource` concept, I think. When I try to bind to a `dataSource` on my page it works fine; But when I try to bind a kendo control to a `remote` datasource within a rendered window, it refuses to fetch.

If I bind only to local data, hard coded data, it works; So I know the `dropdownlist` is working. But I really need to be able to bind to remote data.

I have prepared a **JSBIN** to show this behavior (or lack thereof)

## [JSBIN EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ikoVuSU/3/edit)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. To see the behavior, click on the button to `Create Socket Rail`, then use the `NumericTextBox` to increase the size to any number higher than 0, then click on one of the drawn boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the kendoDropDownList in the `kendoWindow.activate` event (or at least bind the DataSource there). Adapted from your code, this will work:

```
kendoWindowWidget = function (options) {
    // extend the settings options so that we can take
    // explicit configuration from the widget caller.
    var settings = $.extend({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        viewable: true,
        visible: false,
        width: "450px",
        height: "450px",
        activate: function () {
            var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "http://jsbin.com/UYEbOXi/3/js"
                    }
                }
            });
            widgets.windows.sockets.type = $('#socket-type').kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: myDataSource
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");
        }
    }, options);

    var $window = $("<div id='kendow-editor-window'/>")
        .kendoWindow(settings)
        .data("kendoWindow");

    $window.databind = function (e) {
        kendo.bind($window.element, e);
        $window.open().center();
    };

    // return the created combo box
    return $window;
};
```

Adapted JSBin (I removed a bunch of things to make it easier to manage):
http://jsbin.com/uMuFewI/3/edit

Comment: Alright, your example works (thank you so much!) but only if I use the specific line with `remove()` on the template DOM. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Probably because if you don't remove it, you'll have multiple elements with identical ids on the page, which are referenced in the widgets.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. This was really bothering me for a few days now, and I just could not figure it out. I really appreciate the help